# Neo4j graph modelling performance and querability, property to a node or as separate node plus relationship

Tags: neo4j

I am teaching myself graph modelling and use Neo4j 2.2.3 database with NodeJs and Express framework.

I have skimmed through the free neo4j graph database book and learned how to model a scenario, when to use relationship and when to create nodes, etc.

I have modelled a vehicle selling scenario, with following structure

NODES

```
(:VEHICLE{mileage:xxx, manufacture_year: xxxx, price: xxxx})
(:VFUEL_TYPE{type:xxxx}) x 2 (one for diesel and one for petrol)
(:VCOLOR{color:xxxx}) x 8 (red, green, blue, .... yellow) 
(:VGEARBOX{type:xxx}) x 2 (AUTO, MANUAL)
```

RELATIONSHIPS

```
(vehicleNode)-[:VHAVE_COLOR]->(colorNode - either of the colors)
(vehicleNode)-[:VGEARBOX_IS]->(gearboxNode - either manual or auto)
(vehicleNode)-[:VCONSUMES_FUEL_TYPE]->(fuelNode - either diesel or petrol)
```

Assuming we have the above structure and so on for the rest of the features. 
 [image]

As shown in the above screenshot (136 & 137 are VEHICLE nodes), majority of the features of a vehicle is created as separate nodes and shared among vehicles with common feature with relationships.

Could you please advise whether roles (labels) like color, body type, driving side (left drive or right drive), gearbox and others should be seperate nodes or properties of vehicle node? Which option is more performance friendly, and easy to query?

I want to write a JS code that allows querying the graph with above structure with one or many search criteria. If majority of those features are properties of VEHICLE node then querying would not be difficult:

```
MATCH (v:VEHICLE) WHERE v.gearbox = "MANUAL" AND v.fuel_type = "PETROL" AND v.price > x AND v.price < y AND .... RETURN v;
```

However with existing graph model that I have it is tricky to search, specially when there are multiple criteria that are not necessarily a properties of VEHICLE node but separate nodes and linked via relationship.

Any ideas and advise in regards to existing structure of the graph to make it more query-able as well as performance friendly would be much appreciated. If we imagine a scenario with 1000 VEHICLE nodes that would generate 15000 relationship, sounds a bit scary and if it hits a million VEHICLE then at most 15 million relationships. Please comment if I am heading in the wrong direction.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I'm developing a similar model... did this work out well for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modeling is full of tradeoffs, it looks like you have a decent start.

Don't be concerned at all with the number of relationships.  That's what graph databases are good at, so I wouldn't be too concerned about over-using them.

Should something be a property, or a node?  I can't answer for your scenario, but here are some things to consider:

- If you look something up by a value all the time, and you have many objects, it's usually going to be faster to find one node and then everything connected to it, because graph DBs are good at exploiting relationships.  It's less fast to scan all nodes of a label and find the items where a property=a value.
- Relationships work well when you want to express a connection to something that isn't a simple primitive data type.  For example, take "gearbox".  There's manuals, and other types...if it's a property value, you won't later easily be able to decide to store 4 other sub-types/sub-aspects of "gearbox".  If it were a node, that would later be easy because you could add more properties to the node, or relate other things.
- If a piece of data really is a primitive (String, integer, etc) and you don't need extra detail about it, that usually makes a good property.  Querying primitive values by connecting to other nodes will seem clunky later on.  For example, I wouldn't model a person with a "date of birth" as a separate node, that would be irritating to query, and would give you flexibility you'd be very unlikely to need in the future.
- Semantically, how is your data related?  If two items are similar because they share an X, then that X probably should be a node.  If two items happen to have the same Y value but that doesn't really mean much, then Y is probably better off as a node property.

Comment: I think it's definitely possible to create too many relationships.  Not because Neo4j wouldn't be able to handle it, but because it starts increasing the complexity of your queries.  It many cases if the value is pretty straightforward I'd suggest starting with a property.  It's easy to migrate your data and create nodes later, if you want.

Comment: Also, when you say searching for a property for a label is generally slower than finding a node first and then finding it's relationships, is that true when the label/property combination has an index?  I suspect it varies depending on the size of the graph and the density of relationships in different parts.

Comment: Everything is dependent on data volumes and query patterns.  I don't think there are any specific answers about what's faster without knowing those things.   And yes - I agree you can over-create relationships in terms of complicating your queries.

Comment: It's hard to provide exact answers on when property/when relationship. So instead, general rules about "what would suggest property", "what would suggest relationship".  Everything's malleable though depending on query load/data volume

Comment: Thank you @FrobberOfBits for detailed explanations. As far as connectivity of data is concerned well, basically assume somebody wants - a vehicle that is BMW, DIESEL and manual gearbox and 2.1 engine size, red color and manufactured in 2002 with a mileage x and having a price in between y and z ....... the graph should return all eligible nodes.